# Custom http client for wkwebview

Tags: ios, swift, http, webview, wkwebview

Unfortunately the WKWebView does not expose all the information I want to gather when I open a webpage in a WKWebView.

The information I want to gather are:

- all requests headers and bodies from the webview
- all responses including their header and body

What I want to accomplish is some kind of network logging similar to the Network Tab inside the Developer Tools. However the log should be created inside the app.

In Android I did something similar by overwriting `shouldInterceptRequest` in the webview and making the request with `OKHttp` and logging the response, however I have no clue how I could accomplish that with a WKWebView.

I tried overwriting `load(_ request: URLRequest) -> WKNavigation?` however that doesn't catch the requests made by the webview.

I couldn't find a better method to overwrite in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

Comment: Use GCDWebServer, connect your WKWebView locally and load all the content through GCDWebServer as a proxy. Might work. Maybe there are other ways of proxying it.

Comment: I could proxy the first request, but how could I load all the resources from the GCDWebServer?

Comment: By adding a fallback handler on the GCDWebServer, then doing a HTTP Request on all the incoming requests yourself and returning the approriate response. Might need some Dispatch trickery to get the async methods to lock up till you got your data, but it'll allow you to check all the outgoing requests